# Getting parameter values from URL using hibernate without request object?

Tags: java, hibernate

The url is of type : `http://localhost:8080/mdnd_myshelfService_V1.0/myshelf/authenticateUserAndGetHospitalDetails?username=85010352:password=asddddsad2342#$`

In the controller class the following method will be used to authenticate and get hospital data for the username.

```
@GET
@Path("/authenticateUserAndGetHospitalDetails") 
//@path is not complete should be something like /authenticateUserAndGetHospitalDetails?{username}:{password}
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Hospital getAllHospitalData(@PathParam("userId") String userId) {
    log.error("in getAllHospitalData.. " + userId + " | " );
    //need to get parameter values of username and password from url
}
```

Comment: You need to clarify your question. Hibernate has nothing to do with the RESTful web service your code seems to implement. Your real question seems to be in the comments in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `@QueryParam` annotation.

```
@GET
@Path("/authenticateUserAndGetHospitalDetails") 
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Hospital getAllHospitalData(@PathParam("userId") String userId, @QueryParam("password") String password, @QueryParam("username") String username) {

...
```

This will bind the url parameters to their corresponding method parameters. With a url like

```
http://localhost:8080/mdnd_myshelfService_V1.0/myshelf/authenticateUserAndGetHospitalDetails?username=85010352:password=asddddsad2342#$
```

assuming your web server accepts `:` as a parameter separator, then the variable `username` will have the value `85010352` and the variable `password` will have the value `asddddsad2342#$`.

Comment: what will the @path be if request url is  http://localhost:8080/mdnd_myshelfService_V1.0/myshelf/authenticateUserAndGetHospitalDetails?username=85010352:password=asdas@34

Comment: You don't seem to be declaring a path parameter in your `@Path` value. Is there another `@Path` at the class level?

Comment: no Sotirious just want to confirm that @Path("/authenticateUserAndGetHospitalDetails/..........") is there anything i need to add in place of dots.

Comment: You would need `@Path("/authenticateUserAndGetHospitalDetails/{userID}` if you're expecting the `@PathParam` to work.

Comment: Sorry @Path("/authenticateUserAndGetHospitalDetails?..... is there anything i need to add in place of dots.

Comment: You would not put anything after the dots in that case. Url parameters are not part of the path.

Comment: That worked for me Sotirios. But it is taking username as 85010352:password=asddddsad2342#$ , rather than taking the password field seperatly.

Comment: @IshmeetKalsi Seems your server doesn't accept `:` as a parameter separator. Use `&` to separate the password and username.

Comment: @Sotirious the problem is this url format i cannot change one way i am looking is to cut the username String to retrieve the values